# Shell script to replace placeholder from another file

Tags: linux, sh

I am trying to create a shell script which can replace a text in another file.

open> gedit replace_curr_dt.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
curr_dt=$(date)
echo $curr_dt
sed 's/%CURR_DATE%/$curr_dt/g' curr_dt.txt
```

but it does not change the other file content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: In addition to using double quotes, you have to write the output of `sed` to a file, e.g. `sed "s/%CURR_DATE%/$curr_dt/g" curr_dt.txt > curr_dt.txt.new && mv curr_dt.txt.new curr_dt.txt`

Comment: but its only replacing the text I want it to be replaced by current date which we obtain from date

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-i` flag to replace inline.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @HatLess: It _does_ offer an answer. [Please review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). It could use more explanation and, perhaps, an example of how to apply it. But that’s a reason to downvote, not delete.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Noted . BTW, the downvote was not me, just the review.